# Message order breakdown Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

so i have made a chat app when user can chat with each other. I used streambuilder made it order by timestamp. When i send messages i used ***FieldValue.ServerTimeStamp();*** as timestamp. but whenever i spam chats then message order breaks down. It shows messages without any order. I also tried ***DateTime.now()*** but not working. I m using grouped list view. I have been working on my own for long to find any solution but nothing seems to works. Thanks you
Flutter Firebase.

Comment: You should use `Timestamp.now()`. And then when you load the messages from Firestore add `.orderBy('sentOn')` to the query. You should replace `'sentOn'` with the name of the field where you store when the message was sent on Firestore. For more info look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403136/flutter-sorting-cloud-firestore

Comment: I tired this too. Nothing seems to work for me

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"